# Combining GulpJS Tasks

Tags: build, gulp

So I have the following GulpJS tasks that are all related with installing and copying bower files:

```
gulp.task('bower-install', function() {
  var command = 'bower install';
  gutil.log(gutil.colors.cyan('running command:'), command);

  return gulp.src('', {read: false})
  .pipe(shell([
    command
  ]));
});

gulp.task('bower-copy', function() {
  return gulp.src(gulpConfig.bowerCopy.map(function(item) {
    return './bower_components/' + item;
  }), {base: './bower_components'})
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./htdocs/components'));
});

gulp.task('bower-copy-clean', function() {
  return gulp.src('./bower_components')
  .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('bower-clean', function() {
  return gulp.src('./htdocs/components')
  .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('bower', 'Download and move bower packages', function(done) {
  runSequence(
    'bower-install',
    'bower-clean',
    'bower-copy',
    'bower-copy-clean',
    done
  );
});
```

I am doing it this way because I need these tasks to run sequentially one after the other.  While when I run `gulp bower` everything works as expected, I would like to structure this code so that the only exposed task is `bower` as all the `bower-*` are pointless to run by themselves.

Is there any way to write this code so all the `bower-*` task run one after the other but only expose the `bower` task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a gulpfile is just a regular node app, usually when we get into stuck situations like this, it's good to ask "what would we do if we didn't have gulp?"  Here's my solution:

```
var async = require('async');
var del = require('del');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

function bowerInstall(cb) {
  var command = 'bower install';
  gutil.log(gutil.colors.cyan('running command:'), command);
  var childProcess = spawn('bower', ['install'], {
    cwd: process.cwd(),
    stdio: 'inherit'
  }).on('close', cb);
});

function bowerCopy(cb) {
  gulp.src(gulpConfig.bowerCopy.map(function(item) {
    return './bower_components/' + item;
  }), {base: './bower_components'})
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./htdocs/components'))
  .on('end', cb);
});

function bowerCopyClean(cb) {
  del('./bower_components', cb);
});

function bowerClean() {
  del('./htdocs/components', cb);
});

gulp.task('bower', 'Download and move bower packages', function(done) {
  async.series([
    bowerInstall,
    bowerClean,
    bowerCopy,
    bowerCopyClean
  ], done);
});
```

Note that I also sped up your build substantially by not reading in the entirety of the bower_components and htdocs/components directories into ram.

Comment: This works ok however when I was using gulp-shell, it would output the command's output to the screen, is this possible with exec?

Comment: Yes, exec's callback is actually `function (err, stdout, stderr) {` so you just `console.log(stdout)` and `console.log(stderr)`.

Comment: I actually updated your code to use `spawn` instead of `exec`.  Using `spawn` instead of `exec` allows it to steam the output of the child process as it happen where using the callback of `exec` just spits it out once it is done which was not ideal.  Everything else you mentioned was exactly what I was looking for, thanks.